# Programming with old version of Xcode

Tags: systems-programming, xcode3.1

I am a beginner in programming and as I have ideas of making apps what do you recommend to start with?  Is it OK to start with old version of Xcode such as 3.1.1 ? 
Thx for your comments

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't start with the newest version?  An older version won't be any easier for a newbie, if that's what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be a good idea to start with an older version of xcode since you wouldn't get the latest iOS SDKs.